# How to access a file from different folder in a Jenkins shared library?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I have a shared library with the folder structure like this:
vars/all groovy functions.
Test/a java file that does something.

I'm trying to run this file with the command 'java nameOfFile' in a groovy function inside the folder vars.

How can I do that?